# Group by Sub Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables (schema below) and I'm trying to determine how many customers have a flag per category. When I try and use a sub query it just keeps counting how many people have a flag regardless of the category. I've tried adding the group by in the sub query but that doesn't seem to help. I'm sure this is more simple than I'm making it.

*In addition, I need to total count of customers in the same output which I think requires it to have a sub query

```
SELECT p.category, (SELECT count(c.customer_id) from Customer c where c.flag = 'y') as Flagged
from Product p
LEFT JOIN `Orders` o ON p.product_id = o.product_id
LEFT JOIN `Customer` c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by category;

**Schema SQL**

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Customer` (
  `customer_id` varchar(6),
  `name` varchar(6),
  `flag` varchar(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ('000001', 'matt', 'n');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ('000002', 'julia', 'y');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ('000003', 'carol', 'n');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ('000004', 'Riggs', 'n');
  
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Orders` (
  `order_id` varchar(3),
  `order_item_id` varchar(3),
  `customer_id` varchar(6),
  `date` date,
  `product_id` varchar(4),
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`,`product_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES ('aaa', 'xxx', '000001','1.1.2018',"prd1");
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES ('bbb', 'yyy', '000001','1.1.2018',"prd2");
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES ('ccc', 'zzz', '000002','1.1.2018',"prd3");
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES ('ddd', 'www', '000003','1.1.2018',"prd4");

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Product` (
  `product_id` varchar(4),
  `name` varchar(6),
  `category` varchar(7),
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO Product VALUES ('prd1', 'nam1', 'Speaker');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES ('prd2', 'nam2', 'Speaker');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES ('prd3', 'nam3', 'Phone');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES ('prd4', 'nam4', 'Phone');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following amendment.

It uses `LEFT JOIN` to ensure that we will capture all product categories. Moreover it joins customers on `c.customer_id = o.customer_id AND c.flag='y'` ensuring we only capture flagged customers. Finally it uses `COUNT(c.customer_id)` to count the flagged customers. If there are no flagged customers for a product category that `customer_id` will be `NULL` and count will ignore nulls, thereby only counting flagged customer ids.

```
SELECT
    p.category, COUNT(c.customer_id) as Flagged
FROM
    Product p
LEFT JOIN
    Orders o ON p.product_id=o.product_id
LEFT JOIN
    Customer c ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id AND
                  c.flag='y'
GROUP BY
    p.category;
```

| category | Flagged |
| --- | --- |
| Speaker | 0 |
| Phone | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uEkJwkBPzxcPw16bNN1tM6/1)

**Edit 1:**
Also including total customers.

```
SELECT
    p.category,
    SUM(IF(c.flag='y',1,0)) as Flagged,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.customer_id) as total_customers
FROM
    Product p
LEFT JOIN
    Orders o ON p.product_id=o.product_id
LEFT JOIN
    Customer c ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id 
                  
GROUP BY
    p.category;
```

| category | Flagged | total_customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Speaker | 0 | 1 |
| Phone | 1 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uEkJwkBPzxcPw16bNN1tM6/3)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This does work, however, I'll also need the total customer regardless of flag in the same output which would require a sub query I'm assuming.

Comment: @MattSchnelker I've updated the answer to include total customers. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you this worked great. One quick clarification though. What does the 1,0 represent in .....SUM(IF(c.flag='y',1,0)) as Flagged

Comment: We are creating a total using SUM. For each flagged customer we will add 1 otherwise we will add 0. Please remember to upvote and also mark this as the accepted answer so that other stackoverflow users with similar questions will be able to identify answers that worked for each question.